# Is it possible to setup apache-cxf without web.xml?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, cxf

Is it possible to create a webservice with apache cxf (soap/rest) by "using the servlet transport **without Spring and without web.xml** file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Its not possible.
The service will be needing the web deployment descriptor.

You can extend

> [CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFNonSpringServlet.html) for REST

and

> [CXFNonSpringServlet](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/CXFNonSpringServlet.html) for SOAP

web-services in Apache CXF to avoid using Spring, but then you need to register them in web.xml.

You have to either use Spring configuration or web.xml.

Refer: [Apache CXF - How to register a SOAP service without Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817766/apache-cxf-how-to-register-a-soap-service-without-spring)

Comment: Are you sure? https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html#ServletTransport-UsingtheservlettransportwithoutSpring

says its possible to skip spring configuration. I would use Jetty for hosting the servlet.

Comment: You can skip spring configuration but not the web.xml. Refer the link, you need to register the servlet which extends from CXFNonSpringServlet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Took me quite a bit of work to figure this out for my own project and thought I'd share.

In my context, we're using OSGi HTTP Service to publish JAX-RS resources using a Jersey Servlet container and I wanted to do the same thing with CXF for JAX-WS resources.

Your class extending CXFNonSpringServlet should include the following:

```
private Object obj; // JAX-WS resource singleton
@Override
public void loadBus(ServletConfig conf)
{
  super.loadBus(conf);

  JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
  factory.setBus(getBus());
  factory.setAddress("/some/path");
  factory.setServiceBean(obj);
  Server cxfServer = factory.create();
}
```

Note that you may load as many resources within a single servlet as you find needful. Also note that the path in factory.setAddress() is appended to the path at which you register the servlet.

Also note that I'm using the singleton pattern, rather than the handler-class pattern. I'm sure this could be modified simply to fit the other paradigm.